# Resque, Devise and admin authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque

Using Resque and Devise, i have roles for User, like:

```
User.first.role #=> admin
User.last.role #=> regular
```

I want to setup an authentication for Resque. So, inside config/routes.rb i have:

```
namespace :admin do
  mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque", :as => :resque
end
```

And, of course it's accessible for all logged in users.

Is there any way to use a role from User.role? It should be accessible only by users with 'admin' role.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use a route constraint, in your `routes.rb` file:

```
  resque_constraint = lambda do |request|
    request.env['warden'].authenticate? and request.env['warden'].user.admin?
  end

  constraints resque_constraint do
    mount Resque::Server, :at => "/admin/resque"
  end
```

Comment: This does work, however unauthorized users will receive a 404 page and will not get directed to a login page. Keep this in mind when using this technique.

Answer (score 22):

in your `routes.rb` file:

```
authenticate :user, lambda {|u| u.role == 'admin' } do
    mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
end
```

Also, make sure you have `devise_for :users` somewhere in that file

Comment: Your solution totally works and its good because, like the requestor said, we both use the same model for admins and users alike. Thanks!

Comment: That was exactly my problem :)

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer because it's much more elegant and readable.

Answer (score 14):

You can try subclassing the Resque::Server class this way:

```
require 'resque/server'

class SecureResqueServer < Resque::Server

  before do
    redirect '/login' unless some_condition_is_met! 
  end

end
```

And using it in your routes this way:

```
mount SecureResqueServer.new, :at => '/resque'
```

I got this information from [this](http://www.scottw.com/securing-resque-server-rails-3) blog. Give it a try.

Comment: Looks fine, but how could i check curent_user's role from here? Any ideas?

Comment: This solution is much better than using a route constraint. This is because authentication should be performed within the controller, not within the routes.

Comment: Also, the route constraint only creates the route if the constraint is met, otherwise it gives a 404. This is likely to behave differently than the rest of the admin panel.

Comment: this is what I use, remember that you need to include any helpers that you use for authentication, and also init sessions again

Comment: Does anyone have a comparable solution for the new Resque-Web gem? It seems that it doesn't use the Resque::Server, but the Rails Engine to mount the app.

Comment: while it's not clear from this answer where to put the class (note also that the link to the blog post is broken) in my case I've placed the class in an initializer file (under config/initializers/) and it worked fine

Answer (score 10):

There is always the new solution, type this in your routes.rb for rails > 3.1:

```
  authenticate :admin do
    mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
  end
```

And don't forget:

```
devise_for :admins
```

Comment: This does seem like the better idea, but devise seems to redirect to /resque/admin/login if not authenticated. You know of any way to specify the un-authed redirect?

Comment: Check cicloon's solution bellow solves that problem and it's a better

Comment: Regarding your route issue you can try adding "match "/resque/admins/sign_in" => redirect("/admins/sign_in")" in your routes.rb, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731550/devise-authentication-for-sinatra-app-mounted-in-rails

Comment: This worked the best for me versus the other solutions. It also directs you to the proper URL after logging in.. e.g. /jobs -> redirects to /admin/login -> back to /jobs (after successful login)

Comment: This worked for me, but I can't figure out what gem is providing that authenticate method, and it's bugging me...

Comment: Ah, found it: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:authenticate