# Devise. Get current_user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque

It's a following of the [Resque, Devise and admin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283728/resque-devise-and-admin-authentication) question.

Assuming we have:

```
User.last.role #=> 'admin'
```

New issue is: how to get an access to current user (as i have User.role which can be 'admin' or 'user') from this:

```
require 'resque/server'

class SecureResqueServer < Resque::Server

  before do
    #redirect '/login' unless current_user.role == 'admin'
  end

end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything is much more simpler.
To get current User instance directly from Warden, you just:

```
env['warden'].user
```

This way, using Devise, and roles system described above, you can:

```
require 'resque/server'

class SecureResqueServer < Resque::Server

  before do
    redirect '/login' unless env['warden'].user.role == 'admin'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience with authlogic and Resque, but this seems relevant:

http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/776939029/rails3-resque-devise

The author updated his blog and suggests that you add the following to your routes, obviously tailoring it to your specific needs:

```
authenticate :admin do
  mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
end
```

Comment: I have no :admin namespace. Only :user and roles for User, as i have mentioned above.