# How to access Resque Web UI started in EngineYard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, engineyard

I have a project running on EngineYard  , there I've started resque-web

```
Starting 'resque-web'...
'resque-web' is already running at http://0.0.0.0:5678
```

From the command line , I can see the statuses of the workers , there are 3 workers in idle state .

I am not able to see the Resque web UI by visiting xxxx:5678 , if xxxx is where I can access my app . How do I see the workers and their statuses using the Web interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the resque web in the routes.rb like suggested here: 
[Resque, Devise and admin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283728/resque-devise-and-admin-authentication)

```
  resque_constraint = lambda do |request|
    request.env['warden'].authenticate? and request.env['warden'].user.admin?
  end

  constraints resque_constraint do
    mount Resque::Server, :at => "/admin/resque"
  end
```

I found that you might get a "403 - forbidden" error trying to access the resque web via HTTP on engineyard. In this case, try HTTPS instead.