# No route matches [GET] "/resque/overview" when using resque in production with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm using resque for background processing, the route /resque works fine in development, but in production (using passenger) it doesn't, the log/production.log shows the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/resque/overview")
```

when I run the command

```
rails routes | grep resque
```

it shows:

```
/resque                                                                        
      #<Resque::Server app_file="/var/www/webroot/ROOT/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/resque-2.0.0/lib/resque/server.rb">
```

my Gemfile:

```
gem 'resque'
```

my config/initializers/resque.rb

```
require 'resque/server' # this is needed for resque web UI

redis_url = {
  development: 'localhost:6379',
  production: Redis.new(url: 'redis://{user}:{password}/{host_url}:6379/0')
}
rails_env = Rails.env.to_sym || 'development'

Resque.redis = redis_url[rails_env.to_sym]
```

my routes

```
authenticated :user, -> user { user.admin? }  do
    mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question,

The issue was the following line

```
authenticated :user, -> user { user.admin? }  do
```

Which seems to not work with my installed devise version 4.7.3

Once I get rid of it, the /resque route started to work! but I needed a way to restrict viewing that route for admin users only, so here is what I did,

in the config/initializers/resque.rb I added this:

```
require 'resque/server' # this is needed for resque web UI

class SecureResqueServer < Resque::Server
  before do
    redirect '/' unless request.env['warden'].user&.admin?
  end
end
```

Then in routes.rb my /resque route becomes:

```
mount SecureResqueServer.new, :at => "/resque"
```

The above class and route are from [Resque, Devise and admin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283728/resque-devise-and-admin-authentication)

That solved my issue... not sure but it seems that this issue is related to this:

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5019